# New session on every page view when running Facebook application in IFrame in IE and Azure

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-2, azure, facebook-c#-sdk

I am developing a Facebook application and I am using Facebook C# SDK v4.2.1 to help with authentication. I am building the application using ASP.NET MVC 2 and am hosting it in Windows Azure (SDK v1.2).

Everything has been running fine when I had my application in a full browser window, but now when I am attempting to IFrame it in Facebook, I run into session problems. The behavior is that a new session is created on every new page request so the user always comes back to the application's login page. I can see that that Facebook session is valid when Facebook redirects back to the application after authorization, but when I set some session variables and redirect to another page, the session is gone.

When I debug the application locally, both as a standalone web application and in the Development Fabric, everything works fine. It is only when it's published to Azure that I get the problems. I have tried to have a local debug environment that is very similar to production where I have the facebook application at apps.facebook.com/myappnamedev that points to localhost on a specific port.

I just now also discovered that I only see the problem in IE (I am using v.8). Firefox v3.6 and Safari v.5 works fine.

Any ideas to help my troubleshooting? I have spent 10 hours on it and it's getting really frustrating... I am happy to paste code/configuration info if needed, just let me know.

Thank you in advance!

// Peter

Comment: Please include your web.config file and the Facebook application settings you have set on you app.

Comment: I solved this. The redirect from Facebook after authentication landed on different pages in my development environment compared when deployed to Azure. I moved my authentication logic to global.asax instead.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. The redirect from Facebook after authentication landed on different pages in my development environment compared when deployed to Azure. I moved my authentication logic to global.asax instead.